# For each function returning undefined in html

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to call a `foreach` loop in the HTML table to return the same number as rows as the `foreach` returns but I keep receiving `undefined` where the table rows should be.

**This works:**

```
Object.keys(tickets).forEach(function (key) {
  let ticketCount = tickets[key]
  ticketType = ticketType + key + " x" + ticketCount + "\n" 
});
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
    const mailOptions = {
    from: 'test@gmail.com',
    to: email,
    subject: 'title',
    html: `<tr>
            <td align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 24px; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px;">
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" bgcolor="#00B6FF" width="75%" style="padding: 12px;font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px;"><strong>Order #</strong></td>
                  <td align="left" bgcolor="#00B6FF" width="25%" style="padding: 12px;font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px;"><strong>0000224</strong></td>
                </tr>

                ${Object.keys(tickets).forEach(function (key) {
                  `
                  <tr>
                  <td align="left" width="75%" style="padding: 6px 12px;font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px;">Item</td>
                  <td align="left" width="25%" style="padding: 6px 12px;font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px;">$150</td>
                  </tr>
                  `
                })}

                <tr>
                  <td align="left" width="75%" style="padding: 12px; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px; border-top: 2px dashed #D2C7BA; border-bottom: 2px dashed #D2C7BA;"><strong>Total</strong></td>
                  <td align="left" width="25%" style="padding: 12px; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px; border-top: 2px dashed #D2C7BA; border-bottom: 2px dashed #D2C7BA;"><strong>$${totalPrice}</strong></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>`
```

Comment: Did you check any value available in `tickets` object?

Comment: You should use `map` instead of `forEach` since forEach does not mutate. In the callback function you dont actually return anything. Add the `return` keyword. When that is done you will get a string array back from the map call. You then need to `.join()` the entries

Comment: Checkout this repl https://repl.it/repls/OtherDelectableDisks#script.js

Comment: @PatrickHollweck This works. Make it an answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added validation to @PatrickHollweck code, check this out.

```js
const tickets = { "Item-1": "20" };
const totalPrice = 10;

const entries = (tickets && Object.keys(tickets) && Object.keys(tickets).map(function (key) {
  return `
    <tr>
      <td align="left" width="75%" style="padding: 6px 12px;font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px;">${key}</td>
      <td align="left" width="25%" style="padding: 6px 12px;font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px;">${tickets[key]}</td>
    </tr>
  `
}).join(""));

const html = `<tr>
            <td align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 24px; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px;">
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" bgcolor="#00B6FF" width="75%" style="padding: 12px;font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px;"><strong>Order #</strong></td>
                  <td align="left" bgcolor="#00B6FF" width="25%" style="padding: 12px;font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px;"><strong>0000224</strong></td>
                </tr>
                ${entries}
                <tr>
                  <td align="left" width="75%" style="padding: 12px; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px; border-top: 2px dashed #D2C7BA; border-bottom: 2px dashed #D2C7BA;"><strong>Total</strong></td>
                  <td align="left" width="25%" style="padding: 12px; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px; border-top: 2px dashed #D2C7BA; border-bottom: 2px dashed #D2C7BA;"><strong>$${totalPrice}</strong></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>`;

document.write(html);
```